# How to have the template that generates \tableofcontents? Or how to modify the text inside of \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, indexing, templates

I know that to make the table of contents, one can use `\tableofcontents` and it's generated automatically and looks elegant.

I'd like to make a table of contents that contains combined information (from the table of contents generated automatically and from other sources). For that,  how can I get the code of the content from the `\tableofcontents`, for that to be modified?

Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking for.  A picture might help.  In general, things like `\section[<toc line>]{<section heading>}` are used to customize the table of contents.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've edited. I don't have a picture, by customize you mean that, for example, more text can be added to  the Contents? Ultimately that's what I'd like, to modify the text inside the Contents.

Comment: I think my question can be summarized to be more clear. How to have the template that generates \tableofcontents? Or how to modify the text inside of \tableofcontents?

Comment: A template or modifying could be quite difficult.  But there are commands for adding extra stuff, as the answer shows.  Is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: All you've told us is that you want to modify the table of contents.  That doesn't tell us enough to help you.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: But why is the given answer insufficient?  What do you want the output to look like?  I don't know how to access the toc file in Overleaf; you may need to add that tag at your next edit (you don't need `indexing` or `templates`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to customize the `toc`: use an optional argument to your sectioning commands, and/or use `\addcontentsline`.

Thanks to TeePeemm for also noting the use of `\addtocontents`, for which you need to remember that a `\par` at the end is required before the next sectioning command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\hrulefill

\section{What you see is what you get!}

\section[Hi mom]{What you see is not what you get}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{An extra referenced entry here}

\addtocontents{toc}{Extraneous stuff here without page reference\par}

\section{Back to the normal contents line}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you.  Incorporated.